# Как преобразовать данные к такому виду?

Tags: javascript, парсер, parse

Есть вот такой вариант
["a: 1", "b: 2, "c: 3"]
Хочу получить такой
{ "a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это при помощи reduce() и split()

```js
const arr = ["a: 1", "b: 2", "c: 3"]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, el)  => {
  const [key, value] = el.split(": ")
  return {
  ...acc,
  [key]: value,
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо